# Oracle-SQL Developer consumes lot of system's memory. Has anyone faced issues like this. If so is there is solution to avoid this

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

I'm using 19.2 version of SQL Developer and I have switched from TOAD. 
Offlate when I lock up my system and open after an hour or two, I see my system boots up very slowly. 
Most of the system's memory is consumed by Oracle SQL developer. Please see attached screenshot.
Is there any way to avoid the above issues?

Comment: That's not SQL Developer using the memory, it's the jvm. What version of Java are you using? You could try enabling more aggressive garbage collection.

Comment: You can disable features like data modeler, migrations, data miner to save a bit of resources

Comment: If you are not using MySQL developer, please correct your question, to be more accurate. You are allowed to Edit your question.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, Question Edited as Oracle SQL Developer. Hope this makes difference.

Comment: Thank you, it does make a difference.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith. I'm using Java Version 8, (build 1.8.0_201-b09).

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I went through your blog which has suggestions to improve performance. https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/02/sql-developer-tastes-great-less-filling/. I have executed the steps that you suggested. Let me keep check on the performance from now. And about aggressive garbage collector part, I'm going through online resource to understand what is it .

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing what the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) is consuming, resource-wise, not the SQL Developer application itself.

However, there are some things you can try to avoid memory consumption:

1. disable unused, large extensions like migrations, data miner, data modeler
2. close files, connections, and especially query results when you're done working with them
3. use the newest Java 8 or 11 (based on your version of SQLDev)